# Count number of rows where a field is a specific value

Tags: jasper-reports

How do I count how many rows there are where the address field is null (or any other value), and then print the total in the **Summary** band?

I've tried using variables, but couldn't seem to get it working.

- JasperServer 5.0.1
- iReport 5.5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a variable with these properties:

```
Variable class : java.lang.Integer
Caculation : Sum
Reset Type : Report
Increment type : Group
Increment group : YourGroupName
Variable expression : $F{yourField}.equals("") ? 0 : 1
```

Comment: Use `"".equals($F{yourField})` to avoid a potential NullPointerException.

Answer (score 8):

Declare a variable `$V{countNull}` with properties:

```
Variable class = java.lang.Integer
Calculation = Sum
ResetType = Report
Increment type = None
Variable expression = $F{address} != null ? 0 : 1
```

Put `$V{countNull}` into the **Summary** band.

Put `$V{countNull}` into **Detail** band to see its calculation (for debugging).