# Jasperreports Studio - check if rows ins subreport contain a specific value

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

we're currently working on some delivery note Jasper Reports.

I have a main report and the detail band contains a subreport that shows the related articles.
The main report should show a specific scentence but **only when one of the articles has a specific articlenumber**.

I am pretty sure that we have to create two variables (one in the main report and one in the subreport).
Is there a way to iterate over all rows in the subreport return the result accordingly ?

This is what the code would look like in Java (for demonstration purpose):

```
boolean printScentenceInMainReport = false

for (Article a : articleArrayList) {
    if (a.getArticleNumber() == 420) {
      printScentenceInMainReport = true;
    }
}
```

does one of you guys have a solution for my problem ? Is this possible without creating a Scriptlet ? thanks in advance.

Datasource: The reports are linked to a microsoft SQL database. The main and the subreport have their own queries.

Comment: What kind of datasource are you using?

Comment: i added the missing information.

Comment: Hi, you need to set up a variabile in subreport that sets a boolean value (or int value of cnt article number), then you pass it back to main report. (Which is indicated how to do in duplicate) and then use the value in main report to know if to print or not. I know I'm bit lazy closing as dupe... If you have troubles let me know.

Comment: Hi, thats what i was NOT asking for. The text already says that i know how to setup those two variables and use the return value. 

Please re-read the title question. i want to know how to set the variable in the subreport that tells me if one of the rows contains a certain value (thats why i wrote the java demo code).

Comment: Ok, sorry, I added another question that show [How to count where field is a specific value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23473887/count-number-of-rows-where-a-field-is-a-specific-value), hence if count>0 then it's present.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you.